# React HTML ignore Line Break variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how do I make a line break between two variables that will be interpreted in my HTML return?

I want to construct an object with a single description attribute that concatenates two variables containing text with a line break.  Thank

```
   export default function App() {
      let offer = "First line";
      let desc = "Second Line";
    
      let description = `${offer} \n ${desc}`;
    
      let rateToPush = { description: description };
    
      return <span>hello : {rateToPush.description}</span>;
    }
```

Comment: _"how do I make a line break between two variables that will be interpreted in my HTML return?"_ - how would you achieve a line break, if you wrote your HTML manually ...?

Answer (score 3):

```
  export default function App() {
  let offer = "First line";
  let desc = "Second Line";

  let description = <>{offer} <br /> {desc}</>;

  let rateToPush = { description: description };

  return <span>hello : {rateToPush.description}</span>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try I think it can work for my case!

Comment: advice...
 reactJs give you [JSX], use it rather than Back-Tics it is make the code clear and readable

Answer (score 1):

You can use the <pre> tag, also `let rateToPush = { description: description };` seems useless.
You can do:

```
export default function App() {
    let offer = "First line";
    let desc = "Second Line";
  
    let description = `${offer} \n ${desc}`;
  
    return <pre>hello : {description}</pre>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had thought of using the <pre> tag only, even if in my example I show the HTML tag, in my case I really can't modify it.   and I can't edit the css, because I was thinking of adding a "white-space: pre-wrap;"

Answer (score 1):

I think your best solution in this case actually doesn't involve Javascript at all. You can use the `white-space` css property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) with a value like `pre-wrap`.

```css
span {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

It allows you to render whitespace such as newlines and leading spaces.

---

If you need more fine grained control you could split your string by `'\n'`, loop over this new string array and render each string in a `<p>` or something to that effect.

Comment: Thank you, I had thought of using the <pre> tag only, even if in my example I show the HTML tag, in my case I really can't modify it. and I can't edit the css, because I was thinking of adding a "white-space: pre-wrap;"